How to encode diacritics in JSON-LD?
In JSON-LD values I have german characters öäüß - company name, address and so on.
Should they be encoded on any way? Like with RFC1738, öäüß -> %C3%B6%C3%A4%C3%BC%C3%9F
Or no need?

No need, I think. JSON text fields are UTF-8.

JSON-LD is JSON, which allows strings to use the full spectrum of Unicode (UTF-8) characters. Escapes are only needed for a few of these, due to constraints of the format. For instance, a newline is encoded using \n. Nothing outside of the ASCII range needs to be specially encoded.

The JSON-LD spec defines that it uses IRIs, and IRIs do not need to encode non-ASCII characters. It does place some restrictions on usable characters though.
